# Why do we need pageKey and scaffoldKey in this example?

Tags: flutter, dart

In the Google Codelabs about using Responsive Design in Google (Take your Flutter app from boring to beautiful), they use two keys for each route.

```
GoRoute(
  path: '/',
  pageBuilder: (context, state) => const MaterialPage<void>(
    key: _pageKey,
    child: RootLayout(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      currentIndex: 0,
      child: HomeScreen(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Full source code [here](https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/master/boring_to_beautiful/final/lib/src/shared/router.dart).

Why do we need them `_pageKey` and `_scaffoldKey`?

My first understanding was that it is required to store state of NavigationBar and other Scaffold elements or for better animation of switching between pages via NavigationBar.

But I have tried to remove one of them and both, and nothing has changed. Also, the pages are mostly StatelessWidget.

Answer (score 0):

```
MaterialPage Widget=> _pageKey
RootLayout Widget => _scaffoldKey
```

For the `MaterialPage` and `RootLayout` widgets, respectively, the `_pageKey` and `_scaffoldKey` variables serve as special keys. The use of these keys is not necessary for the program to work, however it is used for stability and performance.

- The use of a distinct key for each `MaterialPage` guarantees that the previous page is entirely erased from memory when the user switches to the new one, which can enhance speed and consume less memory.
- distinct keys for each `RootLayout` widget helps to preserve the widget hierarchy while switching between pages. Without a special key, it's possible that the widget hierarchy won't be changed correctly, resulting in errors or strange behaviour.

Generally speaking, employing distinct keys may assist guarantee that your programme is reliable and efficient, especially as it becomes more complicated. Although while deleting these keys might not immediately change how your app behaves, it is typically a good idea to adhere to standard practises, such as utilising distinct keys for each widget.

Comment: Same pagekey and scaffold key is passed in almost all pages in sample code. Can you tell why distinct valueKeys are not used?

Comment: The whole purpose is to group root layout widget and material page widget , the purpose is lost if each route has unique key